# Unable to get Navigation Menu to display in the desired location

Tags: menus

I'm trying to add a menu to my header right next to the products menu dropdown, right here: **(highlighted in green)**

[image]

I've added the following code to my child themes function.php file:

```
// Regster additional Menu for industries page //

function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('industries-menu',__( 'Industries Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

Then as per the next steps, i've added the following code to my child themes header.php

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'industries-menu' ) ); ?>
```

This results in the following situation:

[image]

As you can see, the menu is not showing up in the desired location. Am i missing something here?

Thanks!

P.S: My Website atm is running locally, so i can't share any urls.

P.P.S: I am a complete wordpress beginner, so ELI5 would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to copy the file with the same folder name in the child theme. Then, you need to replace the menu.

Comment: Hi Mohammad,Thanks for the reply. Can you please clarify a bit more. What file and what folder?